# WPF DataGrid inside of a ComboBox SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

In my application I need to select some properties to filter in ComboBoxes. Some of those properties are strings (names, descriptions), or int (Weight, Capacity). Others are inside of a DataGrid, because them represents more complex properties. To do that, I tried to put a DataGrid inside of the ComboBox and when I select one of the rows, the SelectedItem of the ComboBox is that row inside of another DataGrid.

I accomplished to do this work, but for sure there is another way to make it better.

This is what I did:

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox_Consumos_Designacion" Width="200" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_Consumos_Designacion_SelectionChanged">

    <ComboBoxItem>

        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid_Consumos_Designacion" MouseUp="DataItem_Consumos_Designacion_MouseUp"/>

    </ComboBoxItem>

    <ComboBoxItem Visibility="Collapsed">

        <DataGrid x:Name="DataItem_Consumos_Designacion"/>

    </ComboBoxItem>

</ComboBox>
```

Code-Behind C#:

```
private void DataItem_Consumos_Designacion_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
    var row = (DesignacionTEST)dataGrid.SelectedItem;

    var designacion = new ObservableCollection<DesignacionTEST> { row };
    DataItem_Consumos_Designacion.ItemsSource = designacion.ToArray();
}

private void ComboBox_Consumos_Designacion_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox_Consumos_Designacion.SelectedIndex = 1;
    ComboBox_Consumos_Designacion.Width = DataItem_Consumos_Designacion.Width;
}
```

I just want other ways to make it better.

Comment: Don't wrap the ItemsControl (DataGrid) into another ItemsControl (ComboBox). This will only complicate the selected item handling. Instead, I would place the DataGrid inside a Popup and open/close this Popup with a ToggleButton. This way you directly get the selected item from the DataGrid.